# Pull images to Google Kubernetes Engine cluster from an artifact registry in another project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We have a (GKE) kubernetes cluster running in "project A" that needs to get images from an [artifact registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/) that is located in another project, B. How can I configure the project A GKE cluster to have access to pull images from the artifact registry in project B?

Answer (score 0):

You can [pull images from the Artifact registry in another project](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#gke-default-sa).

> If GKE is in a different project than Artifact Registry, [grant](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#grant-repo) the required permissions to the service account.

> For example, to add an IAM policy binding for the role `roles/artifactregistry.writer` for the user `write@gmail.com` with the repository `my-repo` in the location `--us-central1`, run:

```
gcloud artifacts repositories add-iam-policy-binding my-repo \
 --location=us-central1 --member=user:write@gmail.com --role=roles/artifactregistry.writer
```